# Integral of $\int \frac {ax+b}{x^2-ax-b} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

How do I compute the integral $\int \frac {ax+b}{x^2-ax-b} dx$? In the beginning it seemed like it would be something like the logarithm of the denominator, but it's not that simple in the end. Would a trigonometric substitution help in this case?

Comment: Do a partial fraction decomposition first, then you can treat the summands individually on a case-by-case basis (depending on wether the roots of the denominator are distinct or not)

Comment: You can write numerator $N$ as $\alpha D' + c$ where $D'$ is $2\times x-a$ i.e., derivative of denominator. Now, treat the two terms separately, which are easy and standard..

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** The derivative of the denominator is $2x-a$. So , rewrite the numerator as, $$ax+b=\dfrac{a}{2}(2x-a)+b+\dfrac{a^2}{2}$$
Therefore,
$$\int \frac{\dfrac{a}{2}(2x-a)+\left(b+\dfrac{a^2}{2}\right)}{x^2-ax-b}\;\mathrm{d}x=\frac{a}{2}\int \frac{2x-a}{x^2-ax-b}\;\mathrm{d}x+\left(b+\dfrac{a^2}{2}\right)\int \frac{1}{x^2-ax-b}\;\mathrm{d}x$$
For the first integral, substitute  $x^2-ax-b=t$ and you will see the purpose of the hint and the second integral is [standard](https://www.onlinemath4all.com/integrate-quadratic-function-in-the-denominator.html).

Comment: Thank you! Actually the denominator has a $-b$ but I suppose that does not make much of a difference. But how do I get a sum of squares in the denominator for the second integral? I get $x^2-ax-b=(x-a)^2+ax-a^2-b$, what is next?

Comment: @JBuck I have made the necessary corrections, thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: $x^2-ax-b=\left(x-\frac{a}{2}\right)^2-\left(\sqrt{\frac{a^2}{2}+b}\right)^2$. The rest is fairly simple ?

Comment: Thanks a lot, but could you please help me with the second integral as well? I'm having trouble finishing it

Comment: Would be helpful to know which part of the second integral is giving you trouble. Also, don't worry about simplifying it (the answer is not "neat"). Check out problems where  $a,b$ are some fixed integers and the idea might become more clear.

Comment: Oh I thought there was a general solution for all $a,b$. As I said,  when trying to get a sum of squares on the denominator, I get $x^2-ax-b=(x-a)^2 +ax-a^2-b$ and I thought there was always a way to make this a sum of squares. Thank you!

Comment: In one of the previous comments I have mentioned the transformation of the quadratic by [completing the square](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/completing-square.html). That form can be directly used in the standard integral of quadratics in the denominator.